# Bootstrap dropdown renders in wrong place

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to add a dropdown to page header. I read description and tried to implement. Code:

```
<div class="page-header">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10">
     <h1>Page <small>Header</small></h1>
   </div>
   <div class="col-offset-md-10">
     <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>-->
         Settings
         <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
         <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is - drop down renders in wrong place, solutions I googled not working for me.
I made an example: http://www.bootply.com/UKR6JdGVXA

So, what I'm doing wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your markup is not correct. Dropdown container expands to the full width. And since dropdown is positioned absolutely relatively to the container, it shows way much to the left.

Instead of `col-offset-md-10` class use `col-md-2` to fill remaining 2 columns of the 12-column grid.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>-->Settings <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`col-offset-...` classes are used to increase left margin, but they don't change width. Width is controlled by `col-xx-yy` classes.

#### Demo: http://www.bootply.com/t6J4PKBsiR